# JVM and SocksProxy Settings do not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, properties, proxy, jvm, socks

Basic information:
I am trying to get a Java application to connect to a target via SOCKS Proxy. I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) on finding out how to configure proxy settings, which is important, as I cannot change the source code to configure Proxy usage. However, the application did not connect via the proxy.

**Details**
I am using a small custom class for testing this, which has exactly one main method and does this:

```
public static void main(String... strings) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URL url = new URI("http", null, "localhost", 9998, null, null, null).toURL();
    System.out.println("opening connection to " + url.toString());
    URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("connecting");
    c.connect();
    System.out.println(c.getContentLength());
    System.out.println(c.getContentType());
}
```

Then, I start that class using `java <properties> <classname>`.
Properties I have tried so far (single and combined):

1. `socksPropertyHost=localhost`
2. `socksPropertyPort=9999`
3. `http.proxySet=true`
4. `http.proxyHost=localhost`
5. `http.proxyPort=9999`
6. `https.proxySet=true`
7. `https.proxyHost=localhost`
8. `https.proxyPort=9999`
9. `proxySet=true`
10. `proxyHost=localhost`
11. `proxyPort=9999`
12. `java.net.useSystemProxies=true`

Likewise, I added these on the command line, added then to my environment, set the values in `jre/lib/net.properties` and pout them into a comma-separated list which was then passed as `-D$JAVA_OPTS` in a bash script.

All of the connections were refused with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sandbox.Sandbox.main(Example.java:16)
```

Basically, the question(s) here is/are this/these:

Am I doing something wrong here? Is that a bug? Is it just my System?
Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -D does not take a comma separated list.  You need one -D for each property you want to set.

Comment: Okay, to clarify: I added each and every one of the variables on the command line (via `-Done, -Dtwo, -Dthree`), I added them to the environment by adding them to `application.properties`, set each value in `net.properties` and, in desparation, tried a bash script which combines them into one single string.

Comment: Your scenario cannot be easily reproduced from your question, and I do not think that _all_ the connections were refused with the exact same stack trace.

Comment: actually they were. which is wha I am fairly certain that the connection properties I supplied were not honored.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the line

```
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

in the stack trace.  You have configured your JVM to try a SOCKS5 proxy, but the proxy is not responding where the JVM tries to connect.  Typically SOCKS proxies live on port 1080.

Comment: Actually, `SocksSocketImpl` on line 392 is right past the selected proxy part and tries to connect directly, because no proxy was specified. That's why I think that the proxy-selection does not work

Comment: What sources have you used to verify this?  https://github.com/srisatish/openjdk/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/net/SocksSocketImpl.java does not appear to correspond to this stack trace.

Comment: I am unsure about openJDK, I debugged into my own oracle java class. OpenJDK liine would be 384, at least the methods and blocks are the same there